# Is empty string equivalent to boolean value false

Tags: php

I have the following piece of code

```
public function is_logged_in()
 {
   if(isset($_SESSION['userSession']))
   {
     return true;
    }
  }

  if($reg_user->is_logged_in()!="")//I don't understand this evaluation
   {
     $reg_user->redirect('home.php');
   }
```

From my limited understanding, the function `is_logged_in()` is returning a boolean value and the condition on the line I have commented is checking if the returned value it's not equal to an empty string.Is this the right way of doing it?if someone can explain what's going on I will be glad.I am a beginner so forgive me if my questions is a bit silly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your function, `is_logged_in` there are two cases:

- If session set, it returns **True**(boolean)
- If session is not set, function will return **null**

Important point that need to understand here is "boolean values not equal to empty string"

```
var_dump(true != ''); // true  {As boolean not equal to empty string; return true}
var_dump(null != ''); // false
```

Possible solutions for you

- Handle else case in function and `return false`
- Use empty function `if(!empty($reg_user->is_logged_in()))`

From the manual:

The following things are considered to be empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

I hope this will help you to understand.

Comment: Awesome explanation,it blew dust off my head,Hope it will help someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the result of `$reg_user->is_logged_in()` is an empty **string**, you have to use this:

```
if ($reg_user->is_logged_in() !== "")
```

The triple comparasion makes sure that the type is also the same.

For example, `('' == false)` will return true, but  `('' === false)` will return false.

Comment: Listerri -Thanks I get it but is this line `$reg_user->is_logged_in() != ""` legal in the context of the code I pasted in my question?

Comment: What do you mean with legal?
It is going to "work", but it will "work" if the function is logged_in() returns a null, a false, or an empty string, for example.

Comment: I am sorry for using the term "legal" loosely,Anyway you have understood my problem and you have  clarified in your comment above.I didn't know if `logged_in` returns null and also that null is considered empty.